# form_for does not work after removing turbolinks in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I decided not to use the turbolinks because he was giving conflict with some javascript libraries, but after removing it does not submit the forms.

I first removed the turbolinks the `application.js` after I used `rake assets:clobber` and `rake assets:precompile`

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

**_footer.html.erb**

```
  <!-- BEGIN CORE JS FRAMEWORK-->
  <%= javascript_include_tag '/assets/jquery-1.8.3.min' %>
  <!-- Others Javascript libraries here -->
  <!-- END CORE JS FRAMEWORK -->

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@passenger, html: { class: 'form-no-horizontal-spacing', id: 'form-condensed' }) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :passenger_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Nome', required: true %>
<%= f.email_field :passenger_email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email', required: true  %>
<%= f.text_field :passenger_phone, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Telefone' %>
<%= f.text_field :passenger_birthday, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Data de Nasc.', required: true %>
<%= f.text_field :passenger_cpf, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'CPF', required: true %>
<%= f.text_field :passenger_address, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Endereço' %>
<%= f.text_field :responsible_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Nome do responsável', required: true %>
<%= f.email_field :responsible_email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email do responsável' %>
<%= f.text_field :responsible_cpf, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'CPF do responsável' %>
<%= f.text_field :responsible_phone, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Telefone do responsável', required: true %>
<%= f.submit 'Salvar', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-cons' %>
<% end %>
```

Print screen with Javascript loaded: 
[image: jquery and jquery_ujs]

After I remove the turbolinks, I can not submit the form.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: how come you removed jquery but not jquery_ujs

Comment: The meaning of `does not work` is really wide. Try to elaborate.

Comment: @marflar, I have added jQuery with `javascript_include_tag` in `_footer.html.erb`

Comment: asks updated with examples

Comment: What does the log show?

Comment: Noting, because the form not submit, and page not reload, when I click the submit button, it is as if nothing is happening

Comment: Narrow down your problem. It hard to say what is the solution to this problem. First of all take a look at the browser console if there is any javascript error.

Comment: LOL, I solved the problem, it was a javascript library that is conflicting thks